# Pass JSON object to HTML page

Tags: json, rest, parameter-passing

I use Rest API, and I need to pass a JSON object and use it in an HTML/JSP page.

```
public Response getOffers(@FormParam("myParam") String inParam){
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    ..
    return Response.status(200).entity(json).build();
}
```

I need to redirect to another html page, and include the json object as a param ( in order to use it in my js )

Any help is appreciated

Comment: So what's the problem you're facing with your current solution? What's the technology you're using? `jax-rs`?. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: yes, I'm using jax-rs

Answer (score 0):

Usually you define the structure of the object you would like to return as a class, such as:

```
public class Offer
{
  private int id;

  public int getID() { return this.id; }
  public void setID(int id) { this.id = id; }
}
```

Then you can modify the signature of your method to return a list of offer objects:

```
@GET
@Path("/offers")
@Produces("application/json")
public List<Offer> getOffers(/*...*/)
{
  List<Offer> result = new ArrayList<>();

  Offer myOffer = new Offer();
  myOffer.setID(10);

  result.add(myOffer);

  return result;
}
```

Hope I got your question right ;)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Actually my issue is on how I can pass the resulting json object to HTML/JSP.
For example, I need to represent the resulting offers in a table, given that the request to getOffers was submitted through an HTML form not a js.

Comment: Well, that depends on how the client should work. You can either invoke the webservice with a client-side library such as [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) or if the server should render the result, invoke the webservice on the server-side.